# What does top N accuracy mean?

Tags: deep-learning, datasets, scene-classification, accuracy

[Places205-VGG](http://places.csail.mit.edu/downloadCNN.html), a CNN trained model for 205 scene categories of Places Database with  2.5 million images `Places205` dataset has `top1 accuracy = 58.9%` and `top5 accuracy = 87.7%`.

What does `top1` and `top5` (and, in general, top $N$) accuracy mean in the context of deep learning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is explained in this [CrossValidated post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95391/what-is-the-definition-of-top-n-accuracy).

Top1 accuracy means the best guess (class with highest probability) is the correct result 58.9% of the time, while top5 accuracy means the correct result is in the top 5 best guesses (5 classes with highest probabilities) 87.7% of the time.

Comment: is there any script in python which can calculate topN accuracy for a pre-trained caffe model?